# JS Promise called two times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

Having such super simple CRA applicatrion:

*./index.tsx:*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     <Home></Home>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

*./components/Home.tsx:*

```
function Authorize () {

    console.log("--> Authorize  <--")

    let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
        
        let x = 0;          
        
        if (x === 0)
            myResolve("OK");
        else 
            myReject("Error");          
    });     

    myPromise.then(
        function(value) {console.log("--> Promise fulfilled <--")},
    );
}

function Home() {    
    Authorize()    
    return (<div><b>Home Page</b></div>)
}

export default Home
```

When i start the app by `npm start`
I'm getting:

```
--> Authorize  <--
--> Promise fulfilled <--
--> Promise fulfilled <--
```

My question is WHY does the `myPromise.then...` is called TWICE (two lines `Promise fulfilled`) WHILE the `--> Authorize  <--`? is called only ONCE!

Comment: React components in strict mode render twice when you're in development

Comment: @Andy Ray What do You mean by "you're in development"?

Comment: @Daros911 when you're running a dev server as opposed to a production build. E.g. react-scripts start vs build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <React.StrictMode>
```

triggers the double render in order to let us find if there is any unsafe action being made. This won't happen in the production build.

so you can try without `<React.StrictMode>`, then you'll find single log message.

But it is good to have strict mode. you can ignore the double log message.

[CodeSandbox link to try it out](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-sea-hkmz8?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 1):

Simulate onMount with hooks and call it only initially and not on re-renders.
Inside your Home do:

```
useEffect(() => {
    Authorize() 
}, []);
return (<div><b>Home Page</b></div>)
```